# Check if a created object's class is derived from another class

Tags: c++, game-engine

Good evening all, my first time asking a question here, so do let me know if there's any mistakes I made.

Me and my friend have recently begun coding out a component-based game engine, and have ran into a problem that has troubled me for days.
I have a Entity class that stores the list of components that is attached to it, and I have been able to successfully add and remove components to the Entity via templates. The simplified code shown below :

```
class Component
{
    type_index getType() { return std::type_index(typeid(*this)); }

    template<class T>
    bool Component::IsInheritedFrom(){
        return std::is_base_of<T, std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>>::value;
    }

class Entity
{
    std::vector<Component*> ComponentList;

    template<class T>
    T* getComponent(){
         //Just iterate through the vector list and use each component's getType function to check
    }

    template<class T>
    T* removeComponent(){
        //Same as above
    }

    template<class T>
    T* getBaseComponent(){
        //Iterate and use component's IsInheritedFrom function to check
    }
}
```

The issue is that while developing the game, we created some collider component, as well as a colliderManager:

```
class ColliderComponent : public Component
{
    void CheckCollision(Entity* toCheck)
    {
         //Unable to get component
         auto comp = toCheck->getBaseComponent<ColliderComponent>();
    }
}

class SphericalColliderComponent : public ColliderComponent
{}

class AABBColliderComponent : public ColliderComponent
{}
```

For an entity that has a spherical or AABB collider, the IsInheritedFrom function does not work out as intended because the inherited collider is stored as a Component* in the vector list, and thus when the IsheritedFrom function is called, decltype reads (this) as a Component* instead of a AABBColliderComponent*.

I know that using `dynamic cast` works for sure, but I'm not really inclined to use it, and was hoping for some hardcore template to learn to use. The present workaround right now that I have is by having each component class have it's own class name to return as a string, and checking for the class names instead.

Would really appreciate it if someone were to give me pointers in the right direction, thanks! And also was wondering if I should have posted this in the gamedev department instead.

Comment: *"so do let me know if there's any mistakes I made"* - Yes, you've not posted an MCVE. Your code cannot be compiled. Make it compilable and reduce it to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At run time, you want access to type information.

This means you want an RTTI system.  The built-in one is exposed via dynamic cast and typeid.  Typeid is not suitable to your problem.

So this means dynamic cast, or roll your own RTTI system.

One approach for roll your own is to maintain a central list of all types you want to query, then use templates and crtp to populate a vtable with information about what types a given object is.

Another would be a full on dynamic cast replacement, where each type is given enough relected knowledge of it and its place in the class tree to populate your own hand-written rtti query system.

Both of these are bad ideas, because it is similar to someone who does not know how to drive a car proposing to build an airplane to get to the grocery store.

A final approach is to reconsider your design.  If A is a B and is stored with Bs uniformly, then filtering based on being an A not a B is design smell.  Consider tags or something divorced from your class heirarchy to replace type queries.

Comment: Usually, a similar problems that OP has are solved with [Capability Query](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Capability_Query) or [IUnknown/Query Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUnknown).